# Camel split with jsonPath having no results

Tags: apache-camel

In my camel route I want to send part of the output (json path is `$._attachments`) to another endpoint. This works. However, in a few corner cases it appears some of the json objects do not have this element. I guessed this would result in a CamelSplitSize being 0, and tried to test on that; however, the DefaultErrorHandler seems to kick in, rather than completing the route. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class DiscoverAttachmentsFromCouchResponseRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception 
    {
        JsonPathExpression jsonPathExpression = new JsonPathExpression("$._attachments");

        Predicate no_attachments = header("CamelSplitSize").isEqualTo("0");

        errorHandler(
                deadLetterChannel("broker1:queue:dlq.jsonobject.queue")
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                );

        from("broker1:queue:input.jsonobject.queue")
        .routeId("DiscoverAttachmentsFromCouchResponseRoute")
        .threads(2)
        .split(jsonPathExpression)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson,true)
            .to("broker1:queue:with.attachments.queue")
        .choice()
        .when(no_attachments)
            .log("No attachments found.")
            .to("broker1:queue:no.attachments.queue")
        .otherwise()
            .log("A grand total of '${header.CamelSplitSize}' attachments were found.")
        .endChoice();

    }

}
```

**Edit** somethimes the answer is too obvious... I was looking at the wrong place. Why do I always seem to find an answer a few minutes after I asked it? Am direly in need of a rubber duck.

I changed the route a bit; Rather than handling the issue after the split, I should do it prior to the split:

```
    .choice()
        .when().jsonpath("$._attachments", true)
            .to("vm://withattach")
        .otherwise()
            .to("vm://withoutattach")
    .endChoice();
```

Then I only needed two new consumers from the `vm://*` and do the logic there. This seems to work. In jsonpath I can skip the exception which I cannot do in the JsonPathExpression nor in the split();